# How to add bin/ path of the current directory to PATH on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash

Rails applications have a bin/ directory.

There is a way with bash to detect the bin/ dir then add it to the PATH env on the fly ?

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:$PWD/bin`??

Comment: If you mean to look in the current directory's "bin" subdir, then augment PATH=$PATH:./bin  If you mean for it to be added in scripts, then PATH=$PATH:$(cd $(dirname $0) >/dev/null && pwd)/bin -- I am not certain about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/bin
```

or, to make it more permanent, add the above line to your **~/.bashrc** after expanding what `$PWD` should be (i.e.give the absolute path name)